# How can i create tab bar like this? is there any sample?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

how can i create tab bar like this in react native?

[google tasks tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2lB9.png)

is there any sample like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created one using SVG and path and I took help from following Code

https://itnext.io/reactnative-curved-tabbar-dc62e681c24d

also the github code : https://github.com/alex-melnyk/clipped-tabbar

Hope this is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using an Image you can achieve it 
Sample Snack : https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/intelligent-croissant[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={{backgroundColor:'white', height:'10%', bottom:0, position:'absolute', zIndex:1, width:'100%', justifyContent:'space-between',paddingLeft:15,paddingRight:15, flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 5 }}>
          <View>
            <Icon name="bars" size={25} color="grey" />
          </View>
          <View style={{height:'100%',width:100, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <Image style={{width:100,paddingBottom:'20%', position:'absolute', zIndex:3, bottom:'61%' }} source={require('./bottom round 2.png')} />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Icon name="ellipsis-v" size={25} color="grey" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position:'relative',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created one like this with an `SVG` in the middle. Left and right is an empty `view` with a width and a background color. In the middle the SVG component. The floating button is made with an absolute position. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but that's my solution.

Comment: do you have any sample?